# CSS not applying on new page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, css

I just added a new subsite to my collection. However it is not applying the css that is in the style library like all the rest of the sites in the collection are? its just a simple css that has been working fine.

why didn't it propagate to this new subsite?

Comment: Does your new subsite inherit masterpage etc. from its parent?

Comment: Im assuming so. I have a list of other subsites and they all have the css applied. all I did was create a new subsite in the same place. but this one is not inheriting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a custom stylesheet try going to Site Settings on your top level site -> Master Page (under Look and Feel) -> For Theme and Alternate CSS URL check 'Reset all subsites to inherit..'

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. The page was created under a site called "Departments" but I have the navigation set to have this site under a "folder" called 'divisions'. But it was still created as a subsite of divisions

Comment: It's possible it could still be cached after you applied the setting.  Try Ctrl + F5 on the page just to make sure.

Comment: And if it's a subsite under Divisions you went to the Site Settings -> Master Page of Divisions and not Departments then correct?

Comment: I'm just dumb and misread Jordan's post

Comment: Happens to the best of us.  I could've made it a little more read-friendly as well.  Glad it worked!